# Can I have my form update, in designer, with strings from my resource files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, localization, resource-files

I'm getting into globalization and localization.  I'm aware that I can set the localizable property of my form to true and that I'm able to edit the form for that specific culture.  That's great.  My question is am I able to, at the designer, load my resx values into their assigned winforms?  My goal is to edit the size of my winform assets around the translated languages.  This is, obviously, easier if I can see the translations in the designer.  Attached is the code that change the text of my buttons at runtime, but my goal is have this take place during the design phase.

```cs
  buttonTelescopeUp.Text = Resource.TeleUp;
  buttonTelescopeDown.Text = Resource.TeleDown;
  buttonTelescopeLeft.Text = Resource.TeleLeft;
  buttonTelescopeRight.Text = Resource.TeleRight;
```

**Form at runtime**

[image: Image at runtime.]

**Formin design**

[image: Image in design.]

Comment: Just added images, I didn't know how in initial post.  Hopefully the images make the question a bit more clear.  I'd like to see the Spanish text in the designer so that I know what size to make the buttons.  Is this possible?

Comment: I've done similar things at Design-time for Controls, not for a whole form. If you really want to do this, you may have to create controls containing all the functionality and then place that control on a form

Comment: Maybe I misspoke.  The buttons in the example are part of a UserControl does that mean I have hope? lol

Comment: My apologies, I tried to do what I did before to update controls at design time but it didn't work for Language Resources - I tried to replicate the runtime behaviour in Design Mode, but the language part of ResourceManager and updating controls didn't run at designtime, only runtime.